# Connecting HTML Form with PHPMyAdmin Database Issue

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, phpmyadmin

I am doing a test project on [x10hosting.com](http://www.x10hosting.com) making a HTML form sending the text in the textbox to the internal database. I am having an issue connecting x10host PHPMyAdmin and the x10host code. I would really appreciate it if you could tell me where I went wrong. Attached below is my code. If you have any questions please let me know. Thank you.

**index.php**

```
<html>
<h2>Summary:</h2>
</p>
<form role="form" method="POST" action="process.php">
<label>Key Points</label>
<input type="text" id="keypoints" name="keypoints"/> 
</br>
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
</html>
```

**process.php**

```
<?php
//Connecting to sql db.
$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','infinote','','infinote_bank');
mysqli_select_db($connect,'infinote_bank');
//Sending form data to sql db.
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])) {
mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `cornell` (keypoints) VALUES ('$_POST['keypoints']')");
echo "success!";
}
?>
```

Comment: Learn about parametrised queries

Answer (score -1):

Assuming your database configuration is correct, the problem appears to be with the way you are inserting your data: `VALUES ('$_POST['keypoints']')`.

Note that you are using four single-quotes here. PHP considers a string to end as soon as the next quote is met, and is probably getting confused, thinking that you're attempting to insert `'$_POST['`. It would then encounter `keypoints']')` as a syntax error.

Fortunately, `$_POST['keypoints']` is already a `string`, so it can simply be inserted with:

```
INSERT INTO `cornell` (keypoints) VALUES ($_POST['keypoints'])
```

Keep in mind that this is vulnerable to [**SQL Injection**](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection), and to avoid this, you should use parameterised queries, along with validating that your user isn't entering anyhting malicious into the form itself:

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO cornell (keypoints) VALUES (?))");
$stmt->bind_param("s", strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['keypoints'])));
$stmt->execute();
```

You could go more extreme with filtering than this, but this should give you a reasonable baseline.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: We probably shouldn't be recommending injection prone solutions

Comment: True. I'll update the answer to provide a parameterised alternative, although the points raised in my answer will still fix the `INSERT` (albeit vulnerable to injection), and the author didn't ask about vulnerabilities.

Comment: Updated to cover a more secure approach.